# How to numerate a section on index with determinate number?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, numbering

I´m new in the world of beamer.
I wan't to create an index that for each section has a certain number.

For example, I have 3 sections but in the index i want the first section numbered with five, the second with eight and the third with ten.

The most I could do is start the numbering again for each part, with the next code:

```
\makeatletter

 \AtBeginPart{%

    \beamer@tocsectionnumber=0\relax

    \setcounter{section}{0}

    \frame{\partpage}%
}

\makeatother
```

[image: Testing]

Something like in the image

I hope you can help me

Thanks

The code that I am currently using is the following (it is test):

```
\documentclass[20pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\fontshape{sc}

%Information to be included in the titcmdle page:
\title{Sample title}
\author{Anonymous}
\institute{ShareLaTeX}
\date{}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{%
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=0\relax
\setcounter{section}{0}
\frame{\partpage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[part=1]
\tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}

\part{1}
\section{section 1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\only<1>{
\begin{center}
test
\end{center}
}
\only<3>{
\begin{center}
number
\end{center}
}
\only<2,4>{Main
}

\vfill
%\hyperlink<2>{indice<1>}{\beamerreturnbutton{go back}}}
\end{frame}

\part{2}
\section{section 2}
\begin{frame}
\only<+>{testing}
\only<+>{add}
\vfill
%\hyperlink<2>{indice<1>}{\beamerreturnbutton{go back}}}
\end{frame}

\section{section 3}
\begin{frame}
\only<+>{testing }
\only<+>{add }
\vfill
%\hyperlink<2>{indice<1>}{\beamerreturnbutton{go back}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the mapping between the original numbers and your desired numbers arbitrary or does it follow a mathematical rule?

Comment: it's arbitrary, but it increases although without following any mathematical rule

Comment: Understood, I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same technique you use to reset the toc section numbers in each part can also be used to manually adjust the toc numbering of certain sections:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginPart{%
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=0\relax
\setcounter{section}{0}
\frame{\partpage}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[part=1]
\tableofcontents[part=2]
\end{frame}

\part{1}

\makeatletter
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=4\relax
\makeatother
\section{should be 5}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\part{2}

\makeatletter
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=7\relax
\makeatother
\section{should be 8}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\makeatletter
\beamer@tocsectionnumber=9\relax
\makeatother
\section{should be 10}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @PERSONBLINCK2 You're welcome!